# why does 23.04 not play video

Tags: video, intel-graphics, amd-graphics, 23.04

After upgrading computers to Ubuntu 23.04, video has stopped playing. This affects Davinci Resolve, and VLC, probably others as well, those are just the ones I needed after upgrading.
This impacts computers with both AMD and Intel graphics chips.
Audio seems to be working on files, just video playback is broken.
What is missing from 23.04?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Please provide the exact make and model of the computer, GPU, and CPU to help us determine the issue. Thanks.